# ClaimsPrincipalPermission vs ClaimsAuthorization Attributes use different information, which is best to use

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to implement Claims Base Authorization on individual webapi's...  However I don't want the user claims to be tightly coupled to the webapi.  Using ClaimsPrincipalPermissions I get the desired decoupling as I can assign users to resources in the database.  For example

Webapi Method

```
    [ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Operation = "Manage", Resource = "Roles")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetRole(string Id)
    {
        var role = await AppRoleManager.FindByIdAsync(Id);

        if (role != null)
        {
            return Ok(ModelFactory.Create(role));
        }

        return NotFound();

    }
```

Using Custom AuthorizationManager

```
public class AuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
{
    public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        //return base.CheckAccess(context);
        string resource = context.Resource.First().Value;
        string action = context.Action.First().Value;

        if (action == "Manage" && resource == "Roles")
        {
            // check for roles
            //context.Principal.IsInRole("Admin");
            bool hasRolesManagement = context.Principal.HasClaim("ManageRoles", "True");
            return hasRolesManagement;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

I can do the appropriate checks for a particular logged in user checking their claims against the resource they are hitting.  However I can't kick back the appropriate unauthorized response back to the user in this fashion.  Another example I found is below where the webapi is as follows

```
    [ClaimsAuthorization(ClaimType="ManageRoles", ClaimValue="True")]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Then using the custom claims authorization attribute

```
public class ClaimsAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public string ClaimType { get; set; }
    public string ClaimValue { get; set; }

    public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        var principal = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;

        if (!principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        if (!(principal.HasClaim(x => x.Type == ClaimType && x.Value == ClaimValue)))
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        //User is Authorized, complete execution
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);

    }
}
```

This gives me access to the actionContext to send back an appropriately statusCoded response.

THE BIG Caveat to the second approach is to introduce accessability to the api method for a new claim I have to recompile the code.

So my question is how can I get the flexibilty of the first approach where each api is designated as a resource and the claims are assigned in the database to a resource, but still get the flexibility of the second approach where I have access to the action context and be able to return a properly status coded response?  We don't want to have to recompile the code to allow additional roles/claims access to a webapi resource.

I'm new to claims so I don't have a thorough understanding of all the concepts yet so please tell me if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for [ClaimsPrincipalPermission.Demand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.claimsprincipalpermission.demand(v=vs.110).aspx)

> "If the current principal is not authorized for the specified action
>   on the specified resource, a SecurityException is thrown; otherwise,
>   execution proceeds."

The solution would then be to create an exception handler in your solution and return an UnAuthorized Http response. (I really thought ASP.Net did that by default, but I have never checked/reflected over that :)